# How to set click listener to LinearLayout using data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-studio-3.0

I am currently trying to set a click listener to a `LinearLayout` view in the `.xml` layout file using data binding.

I have managed to get it to work well on other views like a `Button` or `TextView`, but for some reason it is not working with a `LinearLayout`.

This is the bare bones of my attempts and I still cannot get it to work:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="@{action::linearLayoutClicked}"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Where `linearLayoutClicked` is my method defined in the action class:

```
public void linearLayoutClicked(View view) {
    // specific logic
}
```

I have also tried with child views and those child views with `clickable` and `focusable` set to false as well as `duplicateParentState` set to `true` and `false`.

That action is exactly the same action that is being used on other views which is working correctly.

Is this a bug or am I doing this incorrectly? Why is this not working for `LinearLayout` but works without any problems for other views?

Comment: Ignore data binding for the moment. If you remove the `android:onClick()` attribute, and you call `setOnClickListener()` on your `LinearLayout`, do you get the results that you want?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, in-code click listener works correctly on the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Hmmm... you might consider looking at the code that gets generated by data binding and see what's in there when you have your `android:onClick` attribute in place. What you have should be OK, though the combination that you're trying (event handler registered via data binding on a non-interactive `View`) may not have been thoroughly tested.

Comment: use `android:onClick="linearLayoutClicked"` instead of `android:onClick="@{action::linearLayoutClicked}"` i tried and its working

Comment: The generated bindings file shows the same structure set for the other working views, there isn't anything different other than the view type.

Comment: Try adding android:clickable=true to the LinearLayout. A wild guess, have not tried myself

Comment: @Thomas Read my sample, it is already using that attribute with that value.

Comment: @Shadow read my previous comment it will solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, was too focussed on the discussion. Sorry.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 I doubt what you said, I just tried and the app crashes due to `Could not find method linearLayoutClicked`

Comment: @Shadow you defined `linearLayoutClicked` method inside your activity right? because i tried and its working

Comment: @akhilesh0707 No, it is a fragment, not an Activity. Now it makes sense why it works for you and not for me. However, thanks to this rubber banding I managed to find what the problem was and fix it. It finally works after 3 days of trying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So everything was set up correctly and the generated bindings file shows the click listener being set up correctly, but for some very odd reason half the bindings were working and the newer ones weren't. By newer ones meaning the `LinearLayout` and all the attempts around it.

What solved the problem was a simple cache invalidation and respective restart and voila, the click listener is working perfectly on the `LinearLayout`. Just remember to set it `clickable` and `focusable` and any child views set as not clickable so they don't consume the event before the parent.

Answer (score 21):

You can handle any view click event like below:

1. Create interface for handle click event like below:

   ```
   interface OnClickHandlerInterface {
       void onClick(View view)
   }
   ```
2. Implement that click listener in action class as shown below:

   ```
   class MainActivity implements OnClickHanderInterface{
       @Override
       void OnClick(View view){
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now bind this interface in XML file:

   ```
   <data>
       <variable
           name="clickHandler"
           type=".OnClickHandlerInterface" />
   </data>
   ```
4. Now register this interface in action class with use of binding object:

   ```
   mActivityMainBinding.clickHandler = this
   ```
5. Now set onClick on any which you want to set click listener. For you it's LinearLayout:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="72dp"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:onClick="@{(v)-> clickHandler.onClick(v)}"
       android:orientation="vertical">
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
6. Now handle click when your linearLayout clicked you can get click on interface which is implemented in action class:

   ```
   @Override
   void OnClick(View view){
       switch(view.getId()){
       case R.id.linearLayout:
           // Handler click and do some actions
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
7. As mentioned above you can get layout click by data binding.

Answer (score 0):

If Invalidate Cache does not work.

then **Rebuild** project from **Build>Rebuild**. Fix errors if any then Rebuild again.