# How to link a click handler to a fragment for data binding?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-databinding

I want to use data binding in a fragment to trigger all my button clicks in handler class. When I run the code below I get the following error.

```
D:\Coding\updatedGithub\AndroidHiveDataBindingFragments\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\com\example\androidhivedatabindingfragments\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.androidhivedatabindingfragments.databinding.FragmentUserBindingImpl;
                                                              ^
  symbol:   class FragmentUserBindingImpl
  location: package com.example.androidhivedatabindingfragments.databinding
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with how I'm passing the context to the Handler class or if I've done some wrong the Data binding.

UserFragment

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FragmentUserBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("First Last");
        user.setEmail("email@email.com");

        binding.setUser(user);

        MyClickHandlers handlers = new MyClickHandlers(getActivity());
        binding.setHandlers(handlers);


        return view;
    }
```

MyClickHandlers

```
public class MyClickHandlers {
    private static final String TAG = "MyClickHandlers";

    Context context;

    public MyClickHandlers(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void myClick() {
        Log.d(TAG, "myClick: ");
    }
}
```

fragment_user

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.example.androidhivedatabindingfragments.User" />
        <variable
            name="handlers"
            type="com.example.androidhivedatabindingfragments.MyClickHandlers" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".UserFragment"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click ME"
            android:id="@+id/btn_Click"
            android:onClick="@{handlers::myClick}"/>

        <include android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        bind:user="@{user}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set click listener to LinearLayout using data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579343/how-to-set-click-listener-to-linearlayout-using-data-binding)

Comment: @ADM cache invalidation provided the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onClick()` of `MyHandlers` has to have the view you click as a parameter, so change it to be:

```
public void myClick(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "myClick: ");
}
```

I guess that will solve the problem, also please instantiate the `MyClickHandlers` with the context instead of activity, as both are different things.

so in `onCreateView()`, add `requireContext()` instead of `getActivity()`

```
MyClickHandlers handlers = new MyClickHandlers(requireContext());
```

Comment: I actually made both of these adjustments late last night and it started to work, do you know the purpose of having View in the parameter?

Comment: @Shawn normally when you bind xml attributes to be accessed programmatically, you need to provide the `View` itself as callback parameter; this way allows the generated data binding class (`FragmentUserBindingImpl`) to bind the java callback method with the XML attribute of that particular view; similarly if you'd a look at binding adapters, they have to have at least a single parameter which is the view, and you can add more parameters as you wish. [This](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#method_references) may be helpful for you

Comment: You can examine that by navigating `FragmentUserBindingImpl` class .